# Should template engine render to outputstream or return a string

Tags: java, template-engine, templating

I am creating a [template engine benchmark](https://github.com/greenlaw110/template-engine-benchmarks) program. Initially the program is designed to test template engine by returning rendered result (as a string). However some template authors raise a concern that A template engine should not return a string as the result, instead it should accept a outputstream or writer instance as the parameter and merge the render result into them. They claim that case represents the real environment a template engine being used.

ASAIK, this statement is not hundred percent right. Play!Framework (at least 1.x) require the template engine to return a String and then put them into the outputstream. And I think it's reasonable to organize it in this way. Think about when if any logic error cause your template rendering process fail, if your template engine output directly into response, then the error becomes unrecoverable. While in Play, you have a good chance to direct the response to an elegant System Error page, rather than to leave a half mess data run to browser.

On the other side rendering directly into output has obvious benefits on performance and resource consumption. I am curious which one should be the better way to go for a template engine designer.

Comment: A stream abstraction (e.g. [Appendable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html)) would be more flexible and allow the engine to produce results that aren't constrained by the limitations of RAM or the String type.

Answer (score 1):

Write to a `Writer`, since that is the lowest common denominator. Your algorithm may prefer to wrap it in a `PrintWriter` for convenience, and this frees you to accept a `FileWriter`, `OutputStreamWriter`, or `StringWriter`.

Writing to a String seems like a bad idea, because in real world usage you are unlikely to need to keep the entire String around for post processing, instead leaving you the ability to write or send the document in small logical pieces—thus your memory consumption patterns will be more realistic.

Remember, if you accept a Writer you can use a StringWriter to get a String. If you use a String you are forced to forever allocate that memory even if a Writer (and streaming API) would suffice.

Comment: StringWriter doesn't save you any memory consumption, it has a built-in StringBuffer inside

Comment: You didn't cover the error recover issue raised in the question. And in the real world keeping a String is not something never happened. Think about you have cache system which allows you to by pass controller and render engine once the http request parameter are the same. Then you put back the string directly into the response. This is also true for Play framework, @CacheFor annotation is there for this purpose

Comment: I meant that if you need a String, they're still equally expensive but easy to produce, and if you don't need one you don't have to allocate that memory. In these comments you argue that between caching and error control (and refusing to accommodate huge templates) you don't need the benefits of a streaming API, which is fine, but it's still the best design choice because it gives you more flexibility when the project evolves. Building your own String from day 1 will rob you of some of that flexibility.

Comment: Remember that your consumer can always pass in a StringWriter themselves and catch any exceptions. They'll then discard the half-used Writer and send their own error. You don't need to bake that into your system at the cost of memory use.

Comment: As a tool designer - the better tool is one that gives the user of the tool more flexibility, ie to be able to write directly to a stream or to a string.

Comment: @JeffBowman, agreed that passing writer is more flexible and leave the control to the API user

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, since returning a string might cause you all sorts of performance issues (from output latency when you need to return a response ASAP to memory issues when someone writes a HUGE template) you shuold definitely go with the stream approach.

and i disagree on the unrecoverable error point as well. you could, for example, add a configuration option to your templating engine to "buffer" in-progress templates (by using a buffered output stream to file/memory and not writing anything to the "real" output stream until its done). in this mode you could implement the exact same error logic. of course, this mode should be off by default - for perfomance.

Comment: someone writes a HUGE template is outside of the discussion. Writing template is totally under the control of project, since they write HUGE template, they can also write HUGE program and bad program and mal program. These are not something a template engine should cover.

Comment: Buffered output stream consume the same amount of memory, turning it off means you lost the error resover again. So your suggestion is either you have performance or you have a more robust system.

Comment: @green - _or_ you buffer to disk and get bufferring and robustness (but slower performance)